# How to group by elements in xslt 2.0 with for-each-group

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xslt-2.0

I am new to xslt and trying to group simple xml element and take a sum using xslt 2.0. Unfortunately  i cannot loop through the node with grouping.
Normal for-each is working good but with group below code is not working.Below is my code for xslt with html.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <head>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h2 class="header" style="text-align:center;">Stock On Hand</h2>


            <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-bordered" style="border:2px solid black;">
                    <tr class="header-center"
                        style="color:black;text-align: center;background: #F1C40F;Font-size:15px;border:2px solid black;">
                        <th style="border:2px solid black;">Warehouse</th>
                        <th style="border:2px solid black;">Stock (Tons)</th>
                    </tr>


                    <xsl:for-each-group select="root/item" group-by="@State_Name">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@Closing_Quantity)"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>

                </table>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mouse</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Power Supplies</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.24</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW4</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.22</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW4</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cables</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.03</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cartridges</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.05</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printer (MFD)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.16</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.77</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jammu &amp; Kashmir</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Jammu</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Copiers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.11</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Networking Cables</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.03</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Servers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.76</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Batteries</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.38</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">CRT Monitors</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.04</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">14.94</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cartridges</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kolkatta</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">West Bengal</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Kolkata</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Copiers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">CEEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">TV</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">&quot;kar&apos;</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.12</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Routers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Servers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.63</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Switches</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.21</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW12</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Landline Phones</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Bluetooth Speaker</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.65</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mixed Electronic Components of Mobile Phones</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mobile Phones</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cables</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.32</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">10.32</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">CRT Monitors</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.31</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Hard Discs</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Keyboards</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">8.16</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">LCD/LED Monitors</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">4.91</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mixed Components of  Desktops</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.25</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mother boards</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mouse</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.56</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Power Supplies</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.61</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.58</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Batteries</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.31</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Laptops/Notebooks</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">13.89</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW4</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW5</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Notepads/Tablets</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.42</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">AC123</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.21</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.06</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printer (MFD)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.70</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">10.69</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cartridges</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Kurla</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Mumbai</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Copiers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.18</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Batteries</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW15</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mobile Phones</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">CD/DVD ROM</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.23</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.16</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Keyboards</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.86</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">LCD/LED Monitors</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.82</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Mouse</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.06</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Batteries</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.21</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Laptops/Notebooks</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW4</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">1.00</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW4</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.14</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters / Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Cartridges</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.02</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printer (MFD)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.61</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.69</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Nagpur</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Maharashtra</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Nagpur</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Adapters /Chargers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW1</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Servers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">2.95</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Central Processing Unit (CPU)</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW2</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Keyboards</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.08</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW3</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Keypads</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">AC123</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW6</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Printers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.86</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
<item type="dict">
    <Warehouse_Name type="str">Near by pass argora</Warehouse_Name>
    <State_Name type="str">Jharkhand</State_Name>
    <City_Name type="str">Ranchi</City_Name>
    <Category_Code type="str">ITEW7</Category_Code>
    <Category_Name type="str">Copiers</Category_Name>
    <Closing_Quantity type="number">0.01</Closing_Quantity>
</item>
```

I am using lxml library to do the transformation in my project.

Here is the code for transformation

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(xml_path)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_path)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
new_dom = transform(dom)
html = ET.tostring(new_dom, pretty_print=False)
```

Below is the transformed result

```
    <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2 class="header" style="text-align:center;">Stock On Hand</h2>
      <div class="container">
         <table class="table table-bordered" style="border:2px solid black;">
            <tr class="header-center"
                style="color:black;text-align: center;background: #F1C40F;Font-size:15px;border:2px solid black;">
               <th style="border:2px solid black;">Warehouse</th>
               <th style="border:2px solid black;">Stock (Tons)</th>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please help me resolving this. Cursor is not even coming inside loop.

Comment: lxml only supports XSLT 1.0 which does not have `xsl:for-each-group`. If you want to use XSLT 2 or 3 with Python you could try Saxon-C from Saxonica http://saxonica.com/download/c.xml as it has a Python binding documented at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/saxonc.html

Answer (score 0):

In the XPath expression of `<xsl:for-each-group select="root/item" group-by="@State_Name">` you have the wrong `group-by` expression as `@State_Name` would group by any attribute (e.g. `<item State_Name="...">...</item>`) while your sample has child elements of that name so simply use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="root/item" group-by="State_Name">
```

The same error is in `<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@Closing_Quantity)"/>` so make that `<xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Closing_Quantity)"/>`.

If you still encounter problems then consider reducing your input to something more minimal to simply demonstrate the problem, together with the output you want and then one you get or any error you get.

Comment: I have done like this as well but still it is not working

Comment: @NikeshKedlaya, see the edit, you had the same mistake to use `@` further down in your code.